# Import data from database to GemFire

Tags: java, in-memory-database, gemfire, in-memory-data-grid, bigdata

I'am working on a project with GemFire.
To import data from database to GemFire, i did a java program that connects to  database and to GemFire and then i select data from database and put
it in GemFire region.
I want to know if there is another possibility to import data continuously from 
database to GemFire ? or if gemfire has connectors to some databases ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only connector I'm aware of is the [GemFire-Greenplum Connector](http://ggc.docs.pivotal.io/ggc/about_ggc.html), I don't think there's any other around.

At the top of my mind, another option to insert data into your region from the database would be to use [Cache Loaders](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/outside_data_sources/how_data_loaders_work.html). Using this approach you really don't need to put data into the GemFire region until someone actually asks for that data.

You might want to have a look at [Keeping the Cache in Sync with Outside Data Sources](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/outside_data_sources/sync_outside_data.html), it contains details about different approaches.

Cheers.

Comment: thank  u , it means that the only solution to load data from HDFS to GemFire is to use a java program as a middleware ?

Comment: A year has passed by. I wonder if there is another option available now?